# Is it possible to see how much your companions approve of you?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

In Dragon Age: Origins, you get a little heart notification every time one of your NPC companions changes their feelings towards you. Is there a way to see what your current approval level is with each character, in order to better manage the romances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the character screen directly below the character model is a bar that shows the approval:

[image]

If you hover over that bar you get a general description and an exact numercial value.

[image]